# Inserting multiple rows query failed

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

```
INSERT INTO EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO)
VALUES  (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-Feb-81',1600,300,30)
      , (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-Feb-81',1250,500,30);
```

Tried to insert two rows at the same time. but failed saying "SQL command not properly ended". Can someone please correct the query?

Error:

> Error at Command Line : 18 Column : 125 Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended" *Cause: *Action:

Comment: Share what error you are getting.

Comment: @Gaurav  INSERT INTO EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) VALUES (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-Feb-81',1600,300,30),(7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-Feb-81',1250,500,30)
Error at Command Line : 18 Column : 125
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below

```
insert into emp  (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO)

select 7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-Feb-81',1600,300,30  from dual
union all
select 7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-Feb-81',1250,500,30 from dual
```

Comment: It worked... THANKS

Comment: @beyou mark it as accepted if it helps

Answer (score 3):

Based on your error message (ORA-00933:SQL command not properly ended), the DBMS is Oracle.

You can use the following query to `INSERT INTO` in Oracle.

```
INSERT ALL  
  INTO EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) VALUES (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-Feb-81',1600,300,30)  
  INTO EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) VALUES (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-Feb-81',1250,500,30)
```

Comment: : getting error   INSERT ALL   
  INTO EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) VALUES (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-Feb-81',1600,300,30)   
  INTO EMP (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) VALUES (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-Feb-81',1250,500,30)
Error at Command Line : 22 Column : 118
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"

Comment: It's missing the `select` statement required at the end. See documentation for [insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html).

Answer (score 1):

To insert multiple records in ORACLE, you need to club your records into `cte`. Or use `Insert All` as mentioned by @Arulkumar.

```
INSERT INTO Emp (EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) 
  WITH names AS ( 
    SELECT 7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,'20-Feb-81',1600,300,30 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,'22-Feb-81',1250,500,30 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names
```

You may find this link for more info on insert command in Oracle.[Link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_BM1LJQ87M5CNIOKPOWPV6ZGR3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax is for Microsoft SQL Server, but your Error Message is from an Oracle DBMS.

You could use the INSERT ALL query:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

See [Official Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423)